# insert bulk data in oracle with validations

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to insert bulk data from emp table to test table in a **single insert**, if one column at least violate the constraint **i want to prevent the user from insert and return error messgaes**. any help please?

create table Test (
 C1 nvarchar(50) not null,
 C2 number,
 C3 date);

insert into Test(C1,C2,C3) select (v1,v2,v3)from emp ;

thanks

Comment: What problem do you have here? The situation you describe is the exact behaviour of Oracle by default ... if a constraint is violated an error is raised and the insert is rolled back.

Comment: Do you want to prevent any data being inserted; or only reject the rows with errors and let the valid inserts complete? You might be looking for [DML error logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables004.htm)? (If not, you might need to read about how constraints work in the concepts guide).

Comment: You.can.catch.the.exception.in.exception.block.so.you.will.be.able.to.show.relevant.error.msg.to.user.Thanks

Comment: please give me example how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

if you have bulk data to insert sql loader is likely a better route to go..

If this is for end users you likely should be using a stored procedure, package, or function.. you haven't given any detail of where the insert code is going to run..oracle will through an exception if you have a constraint in place..

Comment: exactly this is for end users, any help to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I think will work for your query:

```
  BEGIN
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO Test123
             (C1,C2,C3)
         SELECT name,salary,sysdate FROM avrajit;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
             dbms_output.put_line('error msg'||sqlerrm);
      END;
  END;
```

Comment: example.for.your.query

Comment: But you're supressing the error stack. With no exception block you'd still see the error, and get more information about where it occurred.

Comment: But the query will run till the end. If we add the employee details in the exeption block it will show detailed information were it has failed and why.

Comment: Which employee details - you're doing a single insert, how will you know which it failed on? And it won't continue. It sounds like you're describing individual inserts in a loop, and reporting each caught error without fully exiting the loop. Thatisn't what you've shown.But it will also be slower than a single insert of all data.